# Where can I find a list of all XML elements available in sapui5?

Tags: xml, sapui5

I need to build a standard page in sapui5 but I'm not able to find a complete list of the elements available in XML views, so I don't have a full knowledge of what I can build.

Example of XML view:

```
<attributes>
    <ObjectAttribute text="{OrdenId}" />
</attributes>
```

Where could I find a list of all elements available in XML views for sapui5? I can't find any specific standard documentation.

Thanks in advance,
Hoijof.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic] page: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: No recommendations or favourites were requested; this seems like a genuine request for information about representing controls in XML. Perhaps the question might have been better in a "how" format, e.g. "How do I work out which ...", to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no list of elements (controls) in XML Views as all SAPUI5 controls can be used in XMLViews. The control's class name is the element name in a tag. Properties are represented as attributes:

```
<core:View 
controllerName="ui.Main" 
xmlns="sap.ui.commons" 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"> 
<ListBox displaySecondaryValues="true">
<items>
    <core:ListItem text="Item1" additionalText="TextTextText"/>
    <core:ListItem text="Item2" additionalText="TextTextText"/>
</items>
</ListBox>
</core:View>
```